# Secondary monitor does not wake up from standby after screen was locked

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, suspend, power-management, standby

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop, x64, dual 4K monitor, GeForce GTX 960.
When locking the screen, the monitors enter standby mode in about a minute after lock. When unlocking the screen, only one monitor wakes up sometimes, always the same. Issue happened also in Ubuntu 16.04. There as a workaround, I have disabled completely the standby mode for any device.

Is there any workaround known other than disabling standby?